# Plotting circles (circle packing) inside of an area of a leaflet map in R

Tags: r, leaflet, circle-pack

What I would like to be able to is to generate a circle packing plot of values similar as shown here: 
https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/308-interactive-circle-packing/

However, I'd like to be able to plot that within the boundaries of an area on a map, such as a county area using leaflet (or other packages) within R.

I tried running the code provided from the site in their example to generate their plot but I am unable to get it work for me for some reason.

When I try to do it myself within a mapped area, it comes out to be something like below. Thank you for your help.

```
packages <-c("tidyverse","charlatan" "ggmap", "reshape2", "raster", "GISTools", "rgdal", "sp", "maps", "mapdata", "rgeos", "maptools", "rstan", "leaflet")
lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

us <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2)
texas <- subset(us,NAME_1=="Texas")
Dallas <- subset(texas, NAME_2=="Dallas")

leaflet(Dallas) %>%
    addPolygons() %>%
    addTiles()

bb <- bbox(Dallas)
minx <- bb[1]
miny <- bb[2]
maxx <- bb[3]
maxy <- bb[4]
set.seed(23)
LL1k <- data.frame(ch_position(n = 7, bbox = c(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)))
LL1kcol <- as.data.frame(t(LL1k))
colnames(LL1kcol) <- c("lon", "lat")

leaflet(Dallas) %>%
    addPolygons() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircles(lat = LL1kcol$lat, lng = LL1kcol$lon, radius = iris$Sepal.Length*500, color = iris$Species)
```

[image]